# Is there any way to prevent Windows 10 updates from re-enabling Bluetooth?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, bluetooth

We disabled the internal Bluetooth receiver in favor of an external Bluetooth receiver, but have to do this every single time after Windows updates. Any tips?

Comment: How are you disabling it?

Comment: Via the device manager

Comment: Are you not able to disable the internal one in the BIOS?

Comment: Many systems these days don't give bios access

Answer (score 6):

From the *victorian we* I'm assuming this involves multiple systems in a business environment.

You need to do two things - Go to device manager and take down the device ID of the device and *uninstall* the drivers for the device.

You also want to add a group policy rule to *prevent* the device from being reinstalled, technet [has a full writeup here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.06.grouppolicy.aspx) - fire up gpedit (Its available on windows professional editions, and there's ways to do it in home) and go to . Computer Configuration |Administrative Templates | System | Device Installation | Device Installation Restriction | Prevent installation of devices.

[image]

Tap, show, add and add your device ID here.

Since there's no installed driver for the device, and you can't install a driver, the device should stay disabled.

You could probably push the group policy over AD, and do some clever stuff with devcon for multiple PCs, but *that* bit I'm not sure about.

Comment: Caveat: This doesn't work for touchscreens. Instead, reconfigure registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch` | value `TouchGate` changing the data from `1` (enabled) to `0` (disabled).

Comment: This also seems to prevent windows from re-enabling on every restart, which is what I wanted. I successfully disabled my broken 2nd graphics adapter (3D) using this method.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Windows Update partially is a bad idea, since the day that you will
want to use Bluetooth you will find yourself with an outdated driver that
might even be non-functional, and in addition there is no guarantee that this
will solve the problem.

Below is described how to turn off Bluetooth every time Windows starts.

Download the [DevCon.exe utility](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2009/12/16/where-to-find-devcon-exe/).
DevCon is a command-line tool that performs device management functions on local computers and remote computers.

The following DevCon commands are useful :

**List all network adapters**

```
devcon listclass net
```

**Disable a device**

Once you know the (long) Hardware ID of the Bluetooth adapter,
you may disable it by the command :

```
devcon /r disable DEVICE-ID
```

The DEVICE-ID can use wildcards, for example `usb*`.

**Enable a device**

To re-enable the adapter, the command is:

```
devcon /r enable DEVICE-ID
```

If you decide to use Devcon, you could place the disable command in a .bat file
that is placed in the Startup folder or set to run when Windows starts.
Administrator permissions are required for the command.

For more information about Devcon :

- [Windows Device Console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon)
- [Device Console Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-examples) and especially [Example 30](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-examples#ddk-example-30-disable-devices-by-an-id-pattern-tools)

Comment: Wouldn't disabling the Windows Bluetooth Service affect the external bluetooth receiver?

Comment: @Dirk: Yes, you are right. I deleted that option.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Device Manager, find the Bluetooth Adapter you don't want to use, right-click on it and select Disable.

The hardware should remain disabled, even across reboots and patches, until you choose to re-enable it.

Some computers also offer a BIOS option to disable the on-board Bluetooth, and this may also be worth checking into.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the device manager disabled bluetooth adapter doesn't remain disabled across Windows Updates.

Comment: As you also identified, the BIOS option might work, but many more recent machines don't offer this option.

Comment: Yes. Business laptops typically offer this option in BIOS, but I've found the majority of consumer laptops do not. I've seen in the past ways to uninstall the drivers of a device entirely and force the OS not to reinstall them, but I haven't done this in decades. One final option I can think of would be to force the device to accept the wrong drivers, but I don't know if Windows 10 would allow that either.

Answer (score 0):

For built-in hardware; Bluetooth or any other, simply disable it in BIOS or UEFI.  At this point the Operating System will have no visibility or control over it.